# How can I read out the values of dynamically declared bash variables?

Tags: bash, variables, dynamic, declare

I have some trouble with a bash script, maybe someone can help me.

Inside my script, I defined variables dynamically using a loop like this:

```
somecolors="red yellow green blue" # read out of a file, may vary
for color in $(echo $somecolors); do
    # Actually, here is more code that generates the value I 
    # want to set for this variable, that is being written
    # into "$value"
    declare use_color_$color=$value
done
```

The result is that four variables have been defined:

```
use_color_red=1
use_color_yellow=1
use_color_green=1
use_color_blue=1
```

So far so good. But how can I dynamically read these? I thought of suing a "for" loop. For example:

```
for color in $(echo $colors); do
    echo $use_color_${color}
done
```

But this does not work.

How can I compose two variable names to a single one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason to not use an array here?

Comment: There can also be multiple values inside the "use_color_..." variables, e. g. words (for highlighting purposes like "if line contains the word 'foo', highlight it red"). So, I need to combine two arrays, or am I wrong?

Comment: `$(echo $colors)` is redundant; `$colors` by itself is sufficient for iterating over the word-split expansion of the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better use indexed and associative arrays instead. Referencing and dereferencing variable variables that way is really wrong.

```
somecolors=(red yellow green blue)
declare -A use_color

for color in "${colors[@]}"; do
    use_color[$color]=$value  ## Or do you mean use_color[$color]=$color?
done
```

Granting `$value == 1`, when you do `echo "${use_color[red]}"` you'd get `1`.

One variation:

```
declare colors=(red yellow green blue)

declare -A use_color    
use_color[red]=1
use_color[yellow]=1
use_color[green]=1
use_color[blue]=1

for color in "${colors[@]}"; do
    echo "use_color[$color]=${use_color[$color]}"
done
```

Output:

```
use_color[red]=1
use_color[yellow]=1
use_color[green]=1
use_color[blue]=1
```

Similarly:

```
declare -A use_color=([red]=1 [yellow]=1 [green]=1 [blue]=1)

for color in "${!use_color[@]}"; do
    echo "use_color[$color]=${use_color[$color]}"
done
```

Output:

```
use_color[yellow]=1
use_color[red]=1
use_color[blue]=1
use_color[green]=1
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I will also try that.

Comment: This is the solution I prefer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way is using variable substitution. A variable of the form `${!varabc}` will match all previously defined variables beginning with `varabc`. In your case:

```
#!/bin/bash

use_color_red=1
use_color_yellow=1
use_color_green=1
use_color_blue=1

for i in ${!use_color@}; do

    printf "  name: %-16s  value: %d\n" $i ${!i}

done

exit 0
```

output:

```
name: use_color_blue    value: 1
name: use_color_green   value: 1
name: use_color_red     value: 1
name: use_color_yellow  value: 1
```